# trying not to repeat myself (android/java)

Tags: java, android, class, methods

whats up?
i'm a beginner to development and everywhere i read 'do not repeat yourself', so i really mind about repeating myself.
there is a piece of code that i copied and pasted in every single activity of my app, and i suspect there might be a way of not repeating it - maybe creating a class and calling its methods - but i don't know how to implement it.
the code below is what i'm talking about: something i use in my navigation drawer and it's inside the main class of each activity of my app:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "categories baby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (position == 1){

                final Context context = this;

                Intent getUserData = getIntent();
                String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAdActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
                startActivity(intent);


            } else if (position == 2){

                final Context context = this;

                Intent getUserData = getIntent();
                String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AdListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

can you give me some hints on how to reuse this rather than copy/paste?
thanks!

Comment: Is your class already extending another class? If no, you can extract this method in a separate class , and have your classes extend that class. If your class is already extending another class, I see that your method is marked with `@Override`annotation, you could extract this method into a helper class, make it public static final , and have it called in your classes.

Comment: try to extends a basic Activity with this fuction

Comment: hey @Daniel! yes, it already extends Activity. i will try to create that helper class the way you told me and call it in my classes! thanks!

Comment: @fernando Valle, i will play around with that idea too, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an new class that extends `Activity` and implements your code and then make all your activities extend that class.

That code seems to be the implementation of the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, so you can create something like:

```
public abstract class MyActivityWithListener extends Activity 
        implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        ....
    }

}
```

And then your main activity could be something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyActivityWithListener {
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi there @pablo! your example seems to be what the other guys were talking about and i find it pretty clear, i'll try it! thank you very much!

Comment: If this suits your answer please select it as "the answer" ;)

Comment: hey @Pablo, this is a little late but i want u to know that i've just done what you told and it worked! thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

As you can clearly see in the following block

```
        } else if (position == 1){

            final Context context = this;

            Intent getUserData = getIntent();
            String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (position == 2){

            final Context context = this;

            Intent getUserData = getIntent();
            String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AdListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

You are executing the same thing twice, except for the class of the activity. Therefore, you can rip it out into a function like so,

```
        } else if (position == 1){
            beginAdActivity(NewAdActivity.class);
        } else if (position == 2){
            beginAdActivity(AdListActivity.class);
        }
 }

 public void beginAdActivity(Class<?> activityClass)
 {
      final Context context = this;

      Intent getUserData = getIntent();
      String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

      Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityClass);
      intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
      startActivity(intent);
 }
```

And ta-dah, it was written down only once.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an util class like this

```
public class MyUtils{

    public static void jumpToNewAd(Activity mContext){
        Intent getUserData = mContext.getIntent();
        String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewAdActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
    public static void jumpToAdList(Activity mContext){
        Intent getUserData = mContext.getIntent();
        String userEmail = getUserData.getStringExtra("user_email");

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AdListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userEmail", userEmail);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
    public static void jumpToMain(Activity mContext){
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void ting(Activity mContext,String message){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**Call it wherever you want**

```
MyUtils.jumpToAdList(this);
        MyUtils.jumpToNewAd(this);
        MyUtils.jumpToMain(this);
        MyUtils.ting(this,"Catagories Baby");
```

Comment: hey @Biraj, thanks for your answer! i think i get it, will try to use it as well! it's good to get to know different ways to solve my problems!