# Retrofit method response reusing into another activity

Tags: java, android, methods, retrofit2, reusability

How can I get the data from  getDataForId(Integer.toString(1));  by calling the same getDataForId method from the DisplayData class?

I want reuse the same method and get the result.
It doesn't make sense to copy and paste the same method into the other activity class. Then there will be the same code repeated twice.

This is my DisplayData.class

```
  public class DisplayData extends AppCompatActivity {

    Detail reqDetail;
    String BASE_URL = "";
    TextView name;

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_data);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);



        public void getDataForId(final String id) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getApiInterface();
        Call<MyResponse> call = apiInterface.getResponse();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

               if (response.body() != null) {
                MyResponse myResponse = response.body();
                    List<Detail> details = myResponse.getDetails();
                        for (Detail d : details) {
                            if (d.getId().equals(id)) {
                                reqDetail = d;
                                    name.setText(reqDetail.getName());

                                            Picasso.with(DisplayData.this)
                                            .load(reqDetail.getName())
                                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                            .into(image);
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my SecondData class where I want to display the same data response of DisplayData by reusing same methods

```
public class SecondData extends AppCompatActivity {

    Detail reqDetail;
    String BASE_URL = "";
    TextView name;

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_main);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class to make retrofit call like this

```
public class SampleClass {
private DataInterface mListener;

public SampleClass() {
    super();
}

public void getDataForId(final String id) {
    ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getApiInterface();
    Call<MyResponse> call = apiInterface.getResponse();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
            if (response!=null && response.body() != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.responseData(response.body());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

public void setOnDataListener(DataInterface listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface DataInterface {
    void responseData( MyResponse myResponse );
}
}
```

And in your activity just call the class like this

```
SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
sampleClass.setOnDataListener(new SampleClass.DataInterface() {
    @Override
    public void responseData(MyResponse myResponse) {

    }
 });
sampleClass.getDataForId("UR ID");
```

Also in your class store the ID as private memeber variable

```
private Integer YOUR_ID;
```

Then on getting the result compare the result ID with this ID

```
  List<Detail> details = myResponse.getDetails();
    for (Detail d : details) {
        if (d.getId().equals(YOUR_ID)) {
            reqDetail = d;
            name.setText(reqDetail.getName());

            Picasso.with(DisplayData.this)
                    .load(reqDetail.getName())
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .into(image);
          }
    }
```

Comment: hey can you tell me where should i declare the response code into  SampleClass or in other activity class                                                                          {MyResponse myResponse = response.body();
List<Detail> details = myResponse.getDetails();
for (Detail d : details) 
{if (d.getId().equals(id)) {
reqDetail = d;
name.setText(reqDetail.getName());
}

Comment: these things can be done seperate in activities no?list can be maintained different in different activity and also setText method is specific to activity no..you can do that inside that callback method only..it will be formatted also.

Comment: hey bro i have declare the method in other activity class. but its not getting the same id from SampleClass and also i tried to create local String id variable. but i'm not getting any response.  see this error      https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLBkm.jpg

Comment: id is the one that you passed from your activity no..keep that passed id as private member variable,than on getting result check with that id..you wont get the error

Comment: also what I think is you dont need to pass id unless you are using it in the retrofit class..keep that in activity and just check..hope this solves your problem

Comment: check the updated code..if this helps you please upvote and accept answer.

Comment: hey bro can you tell me how to declare my id getDataForId(Integer.toString(1)); as private integer. and also how to apply my id into this  if (d.getId().equals(YOUR_ID))

Comment: what you mean by as private integer?

Comment: save it as a global member variable then pass if you want

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks. I just changed "MyResponse"(responseData paramenter) with a String response.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a BaseActivity and extend the other two from it. Then, you place the method you want to use in both of them in the BaseActivity and make it public so you can use it properly.

Note that anything you need in your method from outside it won't be available in the BaseActivity, so you should either pass in the constructor or declare it in the BaseActivity if possible.

You should also think on how the return of your method should be for you to have access to its results.

You can refer to this question to learn more:

[trying not to repeat myself (android/java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631282/trying-not-to-repeat-myself-android-java)

Comment: so my DisplayData is like basicactivity then after extending it how can i retrieve the same method and get result. can u tell me

Answer (score 0):

So, If you want to use response of one Activity to another Activity,

Then, First save response to List or ArrayList.

And Then Pass data Using `Intent`.

That should do a trick.

Comment: i don't want  just to pass data with intent. i want to call full method from that class and get result each time.